# Connecting Anylogic 8.6 to a redshift database

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift, anylogic

I'm interested in linking up a model in Anylogic 8.6 to a table/view in a Redshift database. This will allow the model to automatically pick up new data to define our populations and run, enabling better operational decision making (i.e. what are we expecting to happen tomorrow, tomorrow always shifting).

This version has native connectivity to an excel spreadsheet or to a SQL Server database. In the FAQ is a step-by-step guide to linking up to MySQL. I've adapted this guide to Redshift, but I'm quite unclear about how to get the connection to actually fire, or how to test if it's actually worked.

Here's what I've done:

1. Downloaded the most recent JDBC driver from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html
2. I've extracted all driver files to the model's folder.
3. I've opened the model in AnyLogic, selected the 'Projects' view and imported the driver JAR file on the 'Dependencies' tab (referenced the file *RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.50.1077.jar*)
4. Gone to the 'Advanced Java' properties of Main and typed the following line in the Import section: `import com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver;`. The model compiles/builds with no error.

I'm not sure what to do next.

- When I go to the database and try to import a table, I still only see the options for Excel/SQL server
- From the 'Connectivity' palette, I've dragged 'Database' into the 'Main' part of the model. I've then
- a) Selected the connection as 'Other database type'
- b) in the 'JDBC Driver' section I've typed `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver`
- c) in the connection URL I've put in the following:`jdbc:redshift://<Server>:<Port>/<Database>?ssl=true&tcpKeepAlive=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` *(this is standard connection string from workbench/dBeaver/KNIME and works with those, all of which are JDBC)*
- d) used my usual username/password that I use for my normal SQL work
- After doing this I still only see the usual options for importing a table. So I added in a 'query' item from the 'Connectivity' palette, and did a simple 'Select * from Table' - but it's unclear how I can get this into my local database...

What are my next steps? Or am I wasting my time here? Redshift connectivity would go a long way to getting our models suitable for more widespread operational use...

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing external database (DB) tables into the built-in AnyLogic DB is a separate thing from reading from / writing to external DBs via a Database object and the Connectivity palette elements. The latter does not affect/change the former.

The latter can be done for any JDBC-compliant DB as you've seen (and that's what the FAQ instructions are referring to).

The former is only supported for Excel/Access and SQL Server. (If you think about it, this requires the schema of the external DB to be translated into a schema for the built-in AnyLogic DB which is actually a standard HSQLDB database; thus by definition this is not a 'universal' operation even with the use of JDBC, hence why only certain external DBs are supported.)

So you can read from the Redshift DB and write into the internal AnyLogic DB to do a 'manual import' (which you could call as part of model initialisation); you can also avoid the Connectivity palette query elements and just do the SELECT queries in the standard Java way, perhaps using a visually-added Database object to get you the connection more easily.

But it's important to remember that this *only* gains you being able to use the built-in visual configuration of internal-DB-linked things like agent populations and properties of library blocks; you can always just do this via queries to the external DB directly (which means a bit more 'manual' code for setting up agent populations, for example). Plus you have the storage overhead of effectively having two copies of a DB, and any performance difference is unclear (trading off the one-off cost of the import vs. any possible improvement of 'local' HSQLDB queries thereafter).

It *may* also be possible to use the underlying AnyLogic Java API which it uses for DB imports (e.g., the `importFromExternalDatabase` function; search the help) to make this slightly simpler, but you'll still need pre-prepared internal DB tables setup (or write code to do something like parse the external DB schema and create appropriate HSQLDB tables).

Comment: Hi Stuart - thanks very much for this. Very nice answer on the different modes of use, although my java is not yet good enough to work out how to actually put it into practice. Never mind, that will come. FWIW, the plan is to have external tables set up in our main DWH, which will then be simple for the model to query. That makes productionising much more simple. Much appreciated, thank you!